# Converting array to string for date format in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: arrays, string, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In my form, when I submit it, I send a notification email that is populated with the form inputs. One these inputs is called `date`.

When I submit the form, it is submitted in the format of an array as follows:

```
[
    'year' => 'yyyy',
    'month' => 'mm',
    'day' => 'dd'
]
```

In my controller, I then send an email to the logged in user before saving the form data to the database.

This is an excerpt of my email's ViewVars:

```
$email->viewVars([
                'date' => $date,
            ]);
```

Because the date is in the form of an array, I get the following error in the email:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP/Template\Email\html\bookingrequest.ctp, line 15]
```

with line 15 being the line where I do an echo of the viewVars variable $date, as follows:

```
<?= $date ?>
```

I was looking up ways of doing a conversion from array to string and have tried the following:

Given `$date = $data['session']['date'];`

- `$date = date('Y-m-d',$date->getTimestamp());` - cannot be used on an array
- `$date = $this->Bookings->Sessions->deconstruct('date', $date);` - found out it was deprecated
- `$date = $data['session']['date']->i18nFormat();` - cannot be used on an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same functionality that CakePHP internally uses to transform array representations of dates to actual date objects, that is utilizing the `marshal()` method of the respective database type object. Once you have a date object, you can then easily format it to whatever you like.

For date-only types you would use `\Cake\Database\Type\DateType`, which should be retrieved via the `\Cake\Database\Type::build()` singleton method, in order to use the same instance as the rest of the application:

```
$dateObject = \Cake\Database\Type::build('date')->marshal($date);
// ... maybe add a check here to ensure that the conversion was successful
echo $dateObject->i18nFormat();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Datebase Access & ORM > Database Basics > Data Types](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#Cake%5CDatabase%5CType)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Type::build()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Type.html#_build)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Type\DateType::marshal()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Type.DateType.html#_marshal)**